# What studios produce dubbed TV shows?

Tags: resources, listening

To improve my listening skills, I often watch television shows. Many Chinese-produced television shows, however, are difficult to understand due to context (for e.g. the setting, situation, and characters are too far outside of my schema).

However, when watching American or British TV shows, dubbed into Chinese, I can usually follow the conversations much more easily, either because I am already familiar with the series or can make guesses based on the context.

I'm trying to compile a list of English and Chinese names of US or UK TV shows which have been dubbed into Chinese. Do you know of any studios which frequently makes Chinese-language dubs for TV? Such information might be a good place to start in finding which shows have been dubbed.

Comment: Even if the title is not the same, you ask for TV shows (both local and dubbed) in that question. Please don't ask the same question again. If you need an answer to this, you can (and must) edit that other question so people might re-open it seeing it has been improved.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Please re-read. And why did you edit my post? Why do you edit all of my posts?

Comment: Helpful editing [is encouraged](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), @Village. It looks to me like Alenanno just removed a bullet point because it looked odd. If you really wanted that bullet point, just put it back.

Comment: A bullet point is used for a list, there was no list there. If you want to underline that the question is there, you can write "So my question is:" before it and make that part italic, if you want, but your question is short. Anyway, please read the [FAQ] and especially the part about [editing](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/faq#editing), like Don Kirkby also linked. P.S. It seems you're taking this too personal. I don't think we should get too personal. :)

Comment: No, I am not taking it personal. I am pointing out a situation which I believe is creating problems for this site. When users post very broad questions, you ask them to make them more specific and close them. Fine, however, when they post very specific questions (e.g. this one), you try to merge them with others to make them more broad. I think you just like to use the moderating tools too much.

Comment: Consider having a look at these: [Respecting poster's style](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/respecting-posters-style) and [When is it (and isn't it) appropriate to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit)

Comment: Actually, I'm providing a service. Whether I like to do it or not, doesn't change the fact that I'm doing something good. And like I said, if you don't like it, you can always rollback. I think those links you posted don't fit to this case, because my edits are not in those "unacceptable" reasons, rather in the "acceptable" ones, like "improve formatting". In the other case, I would have edited too. If you are going to keep answering, please post a meta question so also others can post their opinions and link the question here.

Comment: Please take extended discussions into chat. Please refer to this meta post for information about editing: http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/106/editing-questions-who-what-why-etc

Answer (score 1):

I found this post, *"[What popular science fiction TV shows are available with Chinese dubbing?](http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/topic/30129-what-popular-science-fiction-tv-shows-are-available-with-chinese-dubbing/)"*, which provides links to various services. I am not advocating these services as most of them are illegal, however it will provide you with good information and many examples of movies and series that have been dubbed.

Examples are [verycd.com](http://verycd.com) which now no longer provides links to illegally stream, but will provide you with info of different series that have been dubbed.

[NORMTEAM](http://normteam.com), e.g. http://www.normteam.com/thread-33919-1-8.html

And PPTV.

These should provide you with plenty of examples. However you will need to dig a bit to find what you are looking for and I personally wouldn't attempt to view anything from these sites because the software is so damn dodgy.

The problem is there are literally thousands of shows that have been dubbed in Chinese. If I was after this information and it was just for personal use I would just go to my local Chinese video store and ask them what dubbed series that have on offer.